Sharepoint list created from Excel Export creates a allitemsg.aspx view, also goes to Edit mode
I use Excel to build hyperlinks using Excel formulas, and then export the excel table to create a new sharepoint list. It works great, but the view is quite different.
It creates a default view called allitemsg.aspx?
The very narrow column widths I like a lot.
One minor and one major problem:

I manually have to delete the leftmost column, which is an blank icon in a column  called Type.
The main problem is I don't want to start in Edit mode. The list contains hyperlinks that aren't easy to click in Edit mode.

Can I somehow restore the view to the standard view behaviour? Maybe restore alliteimsg.aspx to allitems.aspx, but keep the nice narrow formatting ?
RESOLVED: Reason for edit mode was that export to sharepoint list from Excel creates a "DataSheet" view, which seems to start in Edit mode. I created a new default view of "Standard" type. The "Edit list" button takes you to a automatic Data sheet view any way, so all is great again.
